# How to exclude list from range in python?

Tags: python, list, range

So I created a list from values within a set range that suited a specific criteria, now later on I want to check all the values within this same range, but excluding the values put into this list.. is this possible? If not is there an alternative?

```
filled_columns = []
for b in range(0,7):
    if board[0,b] == 1 or board[0,b] == 2:
        filled_columns.append(b)
for b in range(0,7) #but excluding values from "filled_columns" list
```

Comment: Show some examples, please.

Comment: @JoeTM_ please add some code so that the problem becomes clear

Comment: Okay it has been added, sorry didn't think an example was needed I assumed it was a simple problem :P

Comment: @JoeTM_ it is, so why haven't *you* tried doing it?

Comment: @jonrsharpe What's that supposed to mean? I didn't know how to do something, that doesn't mean it can't be simple to the majority.

Comment: I mean that, in general, it's nice to show that you've put some effort into figuring out how to this yourself before dumping it on us. This is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Okay I'll refrain from retaliating and just say okay thanks! How would I show I've put some effort into it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, you can just check whether the value `b` in the other for loop exists in the `filled_list` or not, if it does not, do your logic, if it does, don't do anything.

Example -

```
filled_columns = []
for b in range(0,7):
    if board[0,b] == 1 or board[0,b] == 2:
        filled_columns.append(b)
for b in range(0,7):
    if b not in filled_columns:
        #do your logic
```

Or for better performance, you can create filled_columns as a `set` , for which search operation is constant time.

Example -

```
filled_columns = set()
for b in range(0,7):
    if board[0,b] == 1 or board[0,b] == 2:
        filled_columns.add(b)
for b in range(0,7):
    if b not in filled_columns:
        #do your logic
```

Comment: I like the added info about `set` being faster to search than `list` - good solution.

Comment: This seems needlessly convoluted. Why not just use a single comprehension or a single loop that checks for the complementary condition of board[0,b] !=1 and board[0,b] !=2 and then executes the logic? then there's no need for extra lists, sets or loops at all.

Comment: True, but that would only work if the condition is simple, from the question I am not sure if its just an example or if that is the real condition

Comment: The condition can be put in a function and applied as a filter either way, no matter how complex. Traversing the list twice while doing a lookup in a set is both complicated and inefficient. The answer is simply something along the lines of for elements !condition. Not collect all elements condition, traverse again, etc.

Comment: You are basing that assumption on the fact that the elements created in first list is only for condition in second list, what if thats not true?

Comment: Are you saying 'what if the question is something completely different from what was asked?'. Then yes, it might have a different answer. For the question asked, though, your answer doesn't make an awful lot of sense.

Comment: The question says - `So I created a list from values within a set range that suited a specific criteria, now later on I want to check all the values within this same range` . To me it looks like he first created a list with some specific criteria, did some other logic and processing and then ***later on***  he wants to do some logic for values not in the created list.

Comment: the key there is 'within the same range', so the input is the same. The fundamental problem in the question is actually the over-creation of lists, which is not an atypical mistake. The correct solution is, 'traverse the input once, applying logic to the the condition and its complement'. This is both clearer and more efficient in cycles and memory. Probably fruitless to debate this further but I don't think this is a good answer.

Comment: The key here is that - `he created a list` and then `he later on wants to loop through elements in a range not in that list` , thats the exact question of the OP. Now I do not believe the correct answer to it would be to change the question :) .

Comment: The correct answer is, 'you don't need to create an extra list'. Your answer is 'a two pass solution with unnecessary data structures is better than a single pass, no allocation solution because the person asking didn't realize the simpler solution is possible'. Imagine you were reviewing the code you've written in here. Would you leave it like that? What if the range was 1e9?

Comment: Like I said again you are all basing that assumption on that he is creating the list for the sole purpose of using it in the second loop, if so, a normal person would have come here asking a question - 'I want to create a loop which does not loop over certain values' , and not ' i have a list of values that i created previously, and not i want to loop over values that are not in the list ' . Also, looking at the name of the variables - `board`, `filled_column` , I believe this is some kind of game program, so most probably, `filled_columns` is a variable that is used at other places as well.

Comment: That still does not require a two pass solution with sets, @AnandSKumar. It's just terrible code.

Comment: It would require a two pass, if they are really required. I would let the voting system decide which is the better code.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your problem correctly, you can use list comprehension to copy the items into a new list, filtering out those you don't want. For example:

```
list1 = range(20)
filterlist = [4,6,8,9,14]

filtered=[item for item in list1 if item not in filterlist]
print filtered
```

So for your example, replace the last line with:

```
checklist = [b for b in range(0,7) if b not in filled_columns]
for b in checklist:
    # do stuff with b
```

Answer (score 1):

Aren't you just asking for a list of columns that aren't filled? Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, this can be done in a single pass with no extra lists, let alone sets

```
emptycols = [b for b in range(7) if board[0,b] != 1 and board[0,b] !=2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use sets.

```
a  = list(set(range(7)) - set(filled_columns))
```